# How can I avoid Firefox's "you have chosen to open" dialog when I try to download a file?

Tags: macos, firefox

I just want it to save the file to disk, not bring up a dialog and make me click "Save File" each time. The file types that I'm downloading are not listed in Firefox's Applications preferences, and I see no way to add them. I'm using Firefox 3.6.2.

@rlb.usa In the General > Downloads preferences, I have it set to "Save files to [my downloads folder]" rather than "Always ask me where to save files."

Comment: Under Tools>Options>(Main Tab)>Downloads section, there is a radio button 'Always ask where to save files' . Is this checked?

Comment: @rlb.usa: Given that mjtsai is using a Mac it's in the "General" section of the Preferences window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Automatic Save Folder](http://asf.mangaheart.org/) will do what you want.

It has an option to "Automatically accept the 'What should Firefox do with this file?' dialog windows."

It also has a lot more features and options.  It might be overkill for what you want, but you might find those features useful, too.  Especially the ones that allow you to define *where* to save files based on filters.

Comment: This works great—thanks! I like that it lets me set different folders based on the file type.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox's approach to mime types it does not know is to ask first, and allow you to save your choice by checking off the "Do this automatically for files from now on".

[image: Firefox Dialog]

That said there is an extension called [Download StatusBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/26) that will just cause all files to download. (Which may be what you'd prefer)

Firefox's mime types are managed in a file called mimeTypes.rdf in your Profile's folder.

Alternatively, holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key when clicking on a direct download link works for me without fail.

Comment: For me (at least with .plist and .rar files) the dialog doesn't look like that. There is no option to "Do this automatically..." It simply offers Cancel and Save File. So I don't see a way of adding new types, other than perhaps by editing mimeTypes.rdf.

Comment: @mjtsai: Odd. It appears for .rar files for myself whereas .plist files have always displayed as text. Does the Download StatusBar help at all? Or holding option when clicking on links (as that bypasses it completely in nearly any browser on a Mac)

Comment: I'll give Download StatusBar a try shortly. Option-clicking bypasses the dialog, however it sometimes it causes incorrect filenames. For example, everything from FogBugz will be called default.asp. And sometimes if there's a redirect it just downloads a stub file.

Comment: @Chealion Installing Download StatusBar did not help. It still brings up the same dialog when downloading a .plist file.

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a security risk? Websites would be able to force a download without first prompting the user?

Comment: @w3d: The dialog only appears when you choose to (or a link is set to) download. So telling it to auto save the file to your Downloads folder - so it could be (eg. auto open a PDF in Adobe Reader and you have an old version of Adobe Reader) but it's not in this case (as we are only saving the file)